# Triggering 'take picture' command pragmatically in Android

Tags: android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to trigger the 'take picture' command of the default camera application from my application. Application is supposed to take pictures at moments when the algorithm decides to take them. That means anyone does not touch the screen or press 'take picture' button.

Answer (score 0):

I searched in some other places as well and I couldn't find any way to do that.
Then I found out that it is much easier to code a Camera application by yourself.

If you fallow the instructions in this page you'll be able to do it without any problem at all. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest 
Once the camera app is ready, you can insert the extra bit you wanted without any problem.